# Stay at the current page if 404 error occured

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm implementing an error handle for my website: Any time a user requests an invalid url, my site just reloads and does nothing instead of redirecting to a 404 error page.

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit, but... to be clear, you want to intercept invalid urls and keep the user where they are, instead of hitting a 404 page?

Comment: @David  exactly what i want

Comment: [It should help](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine) Even it does not help at least you know how to approach the problem.